# Remove all the keys from nested object excluding one key in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JSON object as follows:

```
x = {
    "prop1": {
        "description": "prop1",
        "dataType": "string",
        "value" : "abc"
    },
    "prop2": {
        "sub1": {
            "description": "sub1",
            "dataType": "integer",
            "value" : 12
        },
        "sub2": {
            "description": "sub2",
            "dataType": "integer"
        }
    },
    "prop3": {
        "input": {
            "name": {
                "description": "input messages",
                "dataType": "boolean",
                "value": false
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "description": "output messages",
            "dataType": "boolean",
            "value": false
        }
    }
}
```

In the above object, I wanted to remove the keys(description, dataType), also remove the key if it doesn't have any **value** key. the expected output for the above one is as below.

```
y = {
    "prop1": {
        "value" : "abc"
    },
    "prop2": {
        "sub1": {
            "value" : 12
        }
    },
    "prop3": {
        "input": {
            "name": {
                "value": false
            }
        },
        "output": {
            "value": false
        }
    }
}
```

My current solution is as follows:

```
function findValue(obj, string, obj1) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
        obj1[string.substring(1)] = obj.value
        return
    }
    for (var key in obj) {
        findValue(obj[key], [string, key].join("."), obj1)
    }
}

console.log(x);
var x1 = {}
findValue(x, "", x1)
var y = {};

function assign(obj, keyPath, value) {
    const lastKeyIndex = keyPath.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < lastKeyIndex; ++i) {
      const key = keyPath[i];
      if (!(key in obj)) {
          obj[key] = {}
      }
      obj = obj[key];
    }
    obj[keyPath[lastKeyIndex]] = { "value": value };
}

Object.keys(x1).forEach(key => {
    const keyPath = key.split('.');
    let value = x1[key];
    if (value != null) {
        this.assign(y, keyPath, value);
    }
});

console.log(y);
```

I did it in a very long way. I first convert my object into a format where each key is the combination of parent and child keys and then converted it into the expected format.

Is there any way to make it better?

Comment: _"any ideas on how to do it with javascript?"_ - Yes but this looks like [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me.

Comment: @Andreas it's not at all homework, in my work, I got same situation. I don't need an exact answer, but asking for possible ways.

Comment: We help with actual code/problems. This is just a "do my work/research for me"... - "...possible ways": a loop + `delete`

Comment: I know that I have to write a recursive function for this, but the logic I am not getting.

Comment: I suggest a few things to get the question re-opened. 1) If you have tried anything yourself, I suggest adding it to the question. If you haven't you should attempt something yourself. 2) The question is currently closed because of focusing reasons. This is due to the fact that you basically ask us to solve the issue for you. Instead you ask about a specific problem. For example "I have the following snippet that produces the output I want, but it does this only for the first level. How can I get this working for nested objects?"

Comment: @3limin4t0r, I have updated my question with my answer. please chek now.

Comment: Your current solution uses `y1` and `z` which aren't defined anywhere. You also define `var y = {}` but don't use `y` anywhere. I'm guessing that `y1` should be `x1` and `z` should be `y`. However that's for you to fix, since I can't be sure. Other than that it should be able to pass the re-open vote.

Comment: sorry for the typo errors, your guess was correct, updated the question.